# Why Shizune's body didn't turn into red like the Orochimaru's hand turned?

Tags: naruto

We saw in original Naruto that after Orochimaru's hands have been cut by Reaper it turned red. Why it didn't happened to Shizune's body after extraction of her soul?

Answer (score 1):

It is different jutsu that one Third did on Orochimaru (Reaper death seal from Uzumaki Clan) and on Shizune was used one of the Six paths Jutsus of Pain. And from what I think the soul that Pain extract is still in this world unlike the Reaper and it travel to another uknown world and that is why body turn purple becouse it is like without oxygen (at least I think Kishimoto wanted to visualize it that way).